# How to attach user CSS to Microsoft Edge?

Tags: css, customization, microsoft-edge, userstyles

In Internet Explorer I can attach my own CSS: for instance, in IE 11 using Tools → Internet Options → General tab → Appearance section → Accessibility → User style sheet → Format documents using my style sheet (https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwHYs.png). In other browsers I use addons like Stylish etc.

Is there any way to do the same in Microsoft Edge? If not through interface options, then maybe through editing its files, or registry, or whatever?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**NOTE**: This answer only applies to the "Spartan" Edge browser: 2015 to 2019, and *not* the Chromium-based Edge browser.

---

(Disclaimer: I have worked on Microsoft Edge)

This is not a supported scenario at present:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt227929%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

> Microsoft Edge does not support user stylesheets.

[An extensibility system is coming for Microsoft Edge](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/extensions-in-microsoft-edge) in an upcoming release, and user stylesheets will be a feature that an extension could provide.

Comment: Where does MS Edge store its own user agent stylesheet? Maybe there is some way to edit it?

Comment: @Dmitry I don't know, sorry - I worked on the JavaScript engine part of Edge, not styling/layout.

Comment: Is this still the case today?  Any hope?

Comment: @klewis Since 2020, Edge is based on Chromium (not just the layout engine, but the whole browser, including UI and everything else) - this means it now supports Chrome's own Extensions, including those that let you set user-defined CSS.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome Webshop there is now at least the extension (other sources) called "Color Links". After all these years we users are allowed to change that stupid purple/blue link combination...