# Is it possible to save modified css/html of another website?

Tags: html, css

Lets say for example that i changed the css of youtube and changed every red in the website to a white in the developer tools. Is it possible for me to permanently save the changes i made?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between default, user and author style sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18252356/what-is-the-difference-between-default-user-and-author-style-sheets). These are called *user style sheets* and the configuration depends on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to save changes permanent but not using developer tools, you should use [`chrome extensions`](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions?hl=en) on desktops.

You can use [stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=en) to apply your CSS on some pages automatically.